# Why tldr | xclip outputs escape codes looking like timestamp, and how to remove it?

Tags: gui, timestamps, clipboard, xclip

**Problem**

I want to copy the output of tldr to clipboard, and then paste that to text editor.

I execute: `tldr pwd | xclip -sel clip`

When I paste from clipboard, I get:

```
pwd
[0mPrint name of current/working directory.More information: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/pwd.

 - [23;22;24;25;32mPrint the current directory:
[23;22;24;25;33m   pwd
[0m
 - [23;22;24;25;32mPrint the current directory, and resolve all symlinks (i.e. show the "physical" path):
[23;22;24;25;33m   pwd -P
[0m[0m
```

I want to get rid of timestamps and also want to know why this is happening.

**Observation**

- `tldr pwd` (without passing into xclip) doesn't display timestamps
- `man pwd | xclip -sel clip` doesn't include timestamps when pasted
- So, only when passing tldr to xclip I find this happening
- The timestamps looks like escape codes

**Environment**

- Static hostname: debian
- Icon name: computer-desktop
- Chassis: desktop
- Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
- Kernel: Linux 4.19.0-17-amd64
- Architecture: x86-64

Comment: Those aren't timestamps. Looks like escape codes for colouring and formatting the text.

Comment: Better-written software automatically turns of color codes when its stdout is not directed to a TTY.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are not timestamps.  They are colour-codes.

According to the [v0.91 Changelog](https://github.com/psibi/tldr-hs/releases/tag/v0.9.1), `tldr` merged a feature to disable colours in July 2021, either by setting a `NO_COLOR` environment variable or using a new `--no-color` command-line option.

Unfortunately, v0.91 of `tldr` is **much** newer than the version currently in Debian (0.6.4)....so, either uninstall the Debian package and compile/install it yourself(*) or submit a bug report asking for the new version to be packaged. Or both.

That's the long-term solution.  In the short-term, using `sed` or something to remove the colour codes from the output (as in @GMaster's answer) is probably the best you do.

(*) I wouldn't normally suggest switching from a packaged version of a program to a self-compiled version (because doing that is likely to cause compatibility problems or issues with upgrading in future), but hard-coded colour codes that can't be disabled are a UI abomination.

Comment: "_hard-coded colour codes that can't be disabled are a UI abomination_" Terminal programs that don't auto-disable color unless a TTY is detected as the output destination are a UI abomination, so `tldr` still qualifies IMHO. Color that you _can't_ disable, that's... I don't even know what that is, it's somehow worse than abominable. It's **#KILLITWITHFIRE**.

Answer (score 3):

Those are color codes generated by `tldr`. Unfortunately `tldr` does not have any option to turn off the colors. But you can pass the `tldr` output through `sed` and get rid of the color codes. Try this:

```bsh
tldr pwd | sed $'s,\x1b\\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g' | xclip -sel clip
```

Alternatively, based on the package jpa mentioned:

```bsh
# install colorized-logs package (for ubuntu)
sudo apt install colorized-logs

tldr pwd | ansi2txt | xclip -sel clip
```

Comment: I might suggest putting the sed command into a small shell script in `$HOME/bin`, perhaps called `decolor`. That way you don't have to remember the precise escape codes or the detailed sed syntax.

Comment: There is also `ansi2txt` from package `colorized-logs` that does the same.